# F# - How to defining multiple generic functions together

Tags: f#

OK:

```
let em inp=sprintf"<em>%A</em>"inp
let bold inp=sprintf"<b>%A</b>"inp
printfn"%s"<|em"blabla"///<em>blabla</em>
```

Trying to define together (with compiling error):

```
let em2,bold2=
    let tag a b=sprintf"<%s>%A</%s>"a b a
    (fun inp->tag"em"inp),tag"b"
```

Error:

> Value restriction. The value 'em2' has been inferred to have generic type
> val em2 : ('_a -> string -> string)
> Either make the arguments to 'em2' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.F# Compiler(30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work, because the F# compiler doesn't consider a tuple to be a "[simple immutable value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/automatic-generalization#value-restriction)":

> The compiler performs automatic generalization only on complete function definitions that have explicit arguments, and on simple immutable values.

> This means that the compiler issues an error if you try to compile code that is not sufficiently constrained to be a specific type, but is also not generalizable. The error message for this problem refers to this restriction on automatic generalization for values as the value restriction.

Instead, I think you have to define them separately, like this:

```
let tag a b=sprintf"<%s>%A</%s>"a b a
let em2 inp=tag"em"inp
let bold2 b=tag"b"b
```

If your desire here is to hide the definition of `tag`, you can make it private.

Comment: Well, I hope I can define that many HTML tags in one line, and, yes, some utility function should be hided.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of centralizing the logic (here: HTML formatting) in a single *factory* function, to enforce the DRY principle.

Instead of fully hiding the `tag` factory function in a closure, we can hide it just from other modules, making it `private` which is usually enough encapsulation. After some renaming:

```fs
let private inside tag content = // 'a -> '-b -> string
    $"<{tag}>{content}</{tag}>"  //  F# 5 interpolated string
```

Then, the usual way in F# to generate the specific function is through partial application. Since the current `inside` function is generic, we can't use the point free notation (meaning implicit parameter `content`) without loosing the generic type:

```fs
let em = inside "em" // ⚠️ obj -> string
```

We have 2 solutions:

1. Have explicit `content` parameter: `let em content = inside "em" content` but it's less elegant.
2. Change the signature of `inside` function and make all parameters of type `string`. In fact, the function `inside` does not care about the type of its parameters - it only cares about `string`s since it casts them to `string` implicitly using the `ToString()` method which can lead to bad surprises when calling this function.

```fs
let private inside tag content =    // string -> string -> string
    $"<%s{tag}>%s{content}</{tag}>" //  %s to indicate parameters are strings

let em     = inside "em"            // string -> string
let strong = inside "strong"
```

Comment: There should always a to-string conversion

Comment: @a_a : if the parameters `tag` and `content` are just `string`, what do you think of the solution 2 ? Is-it a clean answer to your question? If so, please upvote.